# Getting the sequence $\{1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, \ldots\}$ without trig?

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

What's the simplest way to write a function that outputs the sequence:

```
{1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, ...}
```

... without using any trig functions?

I was able to come up with a very complex sequence involving -1 to some complicated formula, but I was hoping there is a more simple solution.

$n$ should start at 0 and go to infinity.

**Update:**

All the solutions you guys provided are great! I wasn't aware there were so many of them. I should have mentioned that I prefer a solution which doesn't use recursion; imaginary numbers; matrices; functions with `if` statements; or functions such as `ceil`, `floor`, or `mod`. I'm looking for something using basic algebra: addition/subtraction, multiplication/division, exponents, etc. However, I will accept anything since I didn't  include this clause originally.

This is what I came up with:

$$a_n=\frac{\left(-1\right)^n+1}{2}\cdot \left(-1\right)^{\left(\frac{n}{2}-\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}+1}{4}\right)}$$

Is there a less complicated way (i.e. fewer terms) to get this same sequence?

Comment: Note that a simple recursion formula isn't possible, but $x_0=1$, $x_1=0$ and $x_{n+2}=-x_n$ works.  That's kind of silly, however.

Comment: How about $x_n = (-1)^{(n - 3\lfloor \frac{n}{3} \rfloor) + 1 }(n - 2 \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor)$ (starting at $n = 1$)?

Comment: What's wrong with $1,0,-1,0,1,0,-1,0,\dots$?

Comment: How is "simplest" defined in a non-subjective manner? Fewest operators? Shortest equation? Something else entirely?

Comment: @MichaelJoyce: I need it as a function that I can input into a calculator.

Comment: Any expression that uses $(-1)^x$ is trigonometry because $(-1)^x$ is another notation for $\cos(\pi x)+ i \sin (\pi x)$. I wonder if there any calculators that do not have trigonometry.

Comment: Your expression can be simplified to $$a_n=\frac{\left(-1\right)^n+1}{2}\cdot \left(-1\right)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$$ a factorisation of Mariano Suárez-Alvarez's answer

Comment: Are you looking for a programming solution or a mathematical solution? If this is a mathematical solution then $1,0,-1,0,-1,\ldots$ should be fine; if this is a programming solution I think this verges on off-topic.

Comment: I'm just curious, what possible reason do you have for this question? Why such limited conditions?

Comment: @Senseful please upload a picture of the calculator that has powers, but no trigonometry, i'm curious :) 
(also: wtf, who uses calculators?)

Comment: @Senseful Your "update" reminds me of those fine prints on coupons and promotions: "Excludes: ..." And you learn about it after everything is done.

Comment: @Vadim'vcherep': I wasn't aware there were so many ways to do this (all of which are great), otherwise I would have included the clause earlier. However, I should have used the word *prefer*, because all these options are valid, as you implied.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Let's try too : $|n \bmod 4-2|-1$

Comment: Can you tell me what the |'s are?

Comment: @JoshuaDrake: the absolute value ( in C language it would be abs(x % 4-2)-1 )

Comment: I thought so, but I must be misunderstanding, what happens for n = 3?

Comment: wow, never mind, I somehow skipped n = 2.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake: note that the formula even works for non integer values (it gives a 'triangle wave').

Comment: You can see the graph of $f(x) = |x \bmod 4-2|-1$ here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D%7C%28x+mod+4%29+-+2%7C+-+1

Comment: @Joshua: I think you are confused because you start counting from $n=1$, whereas Raymond is starting from $n=0$. His answer is great.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Actually, as I commented, I just forgot 2 as I was processing the series.  I've already +1 this since it had no "trigonometry in disguise".

Comment: I call this the 'fold' function. If you are applying it in programming, the behavior across 0 for mod can vary, so it might need to be tweaked.

Comment: @RiverC: yes in C for example % won't work for 'mod' for n negative ($n$ was supposed non negative here). You may use $n mod 4= n-4\operatorname{floor}\left(\frac n4\right)$ instead thanks to the definition of [floor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/floor).

Comment: @Xenon: Thanks for the graph! Let's add another possible solution : $\left(\dfrac {-4}{n+1}\right)$ using the definition of the [Kronecker symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function)

Comment: This function is extremely useful in animation where you need cylical motion at say, 60 frames a second, but don't want the overhead of the circle functions and don't care about the bumpiness.

Answer (score 67):

How about $\dfrac{i^n + (-i)^n}{2}$? (Of course, that is arguably just trigonometry in disguise).

Or as a recurrence:
$a_n = -a_{n-2}$ with $(a_0,a_1)=(1,0)$.

Or $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}^n\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$? (Which can be viewed as a better-disguised version of *either* of the two previous suggestions).

Comment: Beat me to it ...

Comment: The equivalences here are interesting. Note also that the recurrence form is a disguise for the $i^n$ form, and converted to the related homogeneous linear differential equation recreates the trig form.

Comment: [But what if...](http://i.imgur.com/6LUVH.png)

Comment: Ask a silly question, get a silly answer.

Comment: @anon +1 That was hilarious and unexpected. That said, if I see more than one meme post a day on this site, I'm flagging 'em.

Comment: @anon Is that Harry Styles of One Direction?

Comment: @rahul. Count yourself lucky that you don't frequent scifi.SE, where the mother of all meme sites is occasionally referenced, namely tvtropes.org. Over there, any reference to that site usually contains a SPOILER tag, since going there is essentially equivalent to falling into a black hole, time-waste-wise.

Answer (score 39):

Whether this is simplest will depend on exactly what you mean, but the following is a pretty simple description. It's certainly simpler than anything involving trig functions.

$$a_n=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if n is odd} \\
1 & \text{if n is divisible by 4} \\
-1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: This is so brutally simple I never ever were able to find it.

Answer (score 33):

What could possibly be easier than $\Re(i^n)$, $n=0,1,\ldots$?

Comment: totally what I wanted to suggest as well

Answer (score 25):

$$\frac{1}{2} \left((-1)^{(n-1) n/2}+(-1)^{n (n+1)/2}\right)$$

Comment: This is trigonometry.

Comment: @Anixx: Because the exponents are triangular numbers!? :-)

Comment: Any expression that uses $(−1)^x$ is trigonometry because $(−1)^x$ is another notation for $\cos(\pi x)+i\sin(\pi x)$.

Comment: @Anixx $(-1)^n = -1\cdot -1\cdot -1 \cdots (n)$ because here $n\in N$.

Comment: @Eelvex, in that case $\cos(\pi x)+i\sin(\pi x)=(-1)(-1)(-1)...(-1)$ also.

Comment: @Anixx I was talking about the _definition_ of $(-1)^n$, which is *not* trigonometric.

Comment: @Anixx, your last comment is an egregius example of a non-sequitur!

Answer (score 18):

If you have a sequence and have a linear recursion formula generating the sequence, then you can easily transform it into a closed form solution using one of many methods available.

In your case let us start with the simplest recursion: $a_0=1,a_1=0,a_n=-a_{n-2},n\ge 2$. The easiest (if you have access to a computer) way to obtain a closed form solution is to use matrix theory.

First, we rewrite the recursion in matrix form: $\left(\matrix{ a_n \\ a_{n-1} }\right)=\left(\matrix{ 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 }\right)\left(\matrix{ a_{n-1} \\ a_{n-2} }\right)$.

From here we get: $$\left(\matrix{ a_n \\ a_{n-1} }\right)=\left(\matrix{ 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 }\right)^{n-1}\left(\matrix{ a_1 \\ a_0 }\right)=\left(\matrix{ 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 }\right)^{n-1}\left(\matrix{ 0 \\ 1 }\right)$$ A standard method to proceed at this point is to diagonalize the matrix (here the computer is your best friend, for example: [use Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diagonalize%20%5B%5B0,-1%5D,%5B1,0%5D%5D)): $$\left(\matrix{ 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 }\right)=\left(\matrix{ -i & i \\ 1 & 1 }\right)\left(\matrix{ -i & 0 \\ 0 & i }\right)\left(\matrix{ -i & i \\ 1 & 1 }\right)^{-1}$$ $$\left(\matrix{ a_n \\ a_{n-1} }\right)=\left(\matrix{ -i & i \\ 1 & 1 }\right)\left(\matrix{ (-i)^{n-1} & 0 \\ 0 & i^{n-1} }\right)\left(\matrix{ i/2 & 1/2 \\ -i/2 & 1/2 }\right)\left(\matrix{ 0 \\ 1 }\right)$$
and $$a_n=\frac{1}{2}(-i)^n+\frac{1}{2}i^n$$

We could start from another form of recursion: for example, $a_0=1, a_1=0, a_2=-1$ and $a_n=-(a_{n-3}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-1})$, $n\ge 3$. Then write down a 3x3 matrix representing the recursion, diagonalize it, and obtain... well, the same solution. So, it does not matter how you represent the linear recursion: in general, you are going to obtain the same closed form solution.

Another way to find a closed form solution is to use generating functions. Using generating functions is easier to do by hand (no need to diagonalize and invert matrices).

Comment: Great answer. I hope it is not underrated.

Answer (score 17):

The specific sequence is not essential. You are asking how to construct a function with period 4.  Linear combinations of shifts of one $n$-periodic function can be used to write down any other $n$-periodic function, so they are all equally good in that sense.  The trouble is to get at a sequence with period 4 without basing it on another one already known to have that period, such as $i^n$.

The answer is *division by 2* which, as you can see, appears in all the answers that are not built from a $\mod 4$ operation.

If you are allowed as a primitive one integer function $f(n)$ of period 2, such as $(-1)^n$, and division by 2, then any function of order $2^k$ can be constructed.

From $f(n)$ and possible divisions by 2, one can construct the parity function $p(n) = n \mod 2$.  Using that and more divisions by two, one can construct for each $i$ the function that equals the $i$'th binary digit of $n$.

I don't think there is a way to avoid as ingredients in the formula at least one 2-periodic function given as a primitive, and division by 2.  Except by providing a 4-periodic operation at the start, in which case linear combinations are enough.

Answer (score 7):

My favourite is $(-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}(n \text{ mod } 2 )$. Seems quite tidy compared to other possible expressions.

Answer (score 4):

This may be silly, but ${(-1)^{\lceil n/2\rceil+1} }\cdot{(-1)^{n+1}+1\over 2}$, where $\lceil m\rceil$ is the smallest integer greater than or equal to $m$.

Answer (score 4):

If you like the programming language C, you could write

```
2*!(n % 4) - !(n % 2)
```

which works for `n` from 0 up to the point where `n` overflows your integer size.

Comment: If `n` is an `unsigned` it'll keep on working past integer overflow, too.

Answer (score 3):

I think that |n mod 4−2|−1 is a great solution.
Here is some that not require absolute value:

(1 - (n mod 4))((n+1) mod 2)

The logic behind it is:
n mod 2 gives 0, 1, 0, 1.. because we want all odd numbers to be 0 we use n+1 mod 2.
Than we use (1 - (n mod 4)) to make 0 input to output 1 and 2 input to output -1. n mod 4 is just to limit the numbers between 0 and 3.

Cheers.

Comment: This can be made more symmetrical as $(1 - n\bmod 4)(1 - n \bmod 2)$

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to avoid imaginary numbers, you need to ensure that $-1$ takes an integer power: so your answer seems pretty efficient in that respect.

If we relax the condition of avoiding imaginary numbers, then we no longer require integer powers, because we can allow $i = (-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ as in several other answers.

Alternatively, if we allow clock arithmetic/modular arithmetic, or rounding with ceiling or floor, it becomes much more straightforward to engineer a discrete, repeating pattern.

Otherwise, I can simplify your answer just a little (require fewer operations):

$$a_n=\frac{\left(-1\right)^n+1}{2}\cdot \left(-1\right)^{\left(\frac{2n-1+\left(-1\right)^{n}}{4}\right)}$$

Comment: Any expression that uses $(-1)^x$ is trigonometry because $(-1)^x$ is another notation for $\cos(\pi x)+ i \sin (\pi x)$

Comment: @Anixx he needs to be able to enter it into a calculator, presumably without trigonometric functions. Most calculators can evaluate exponents, this should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n=\frac{(-1)^n+1}{2}(-1)^{\frac{(-1)^n-1}{2}}$$

But, technically that's using imaginary because it is really doing
$$a_n=\frac{(-1)^n+1}{2}i^{(-1)^n-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

With binary operators (not the prettiest solution but probably the fastest):

((n&1)^1) - ((n&2) & ~((n&1)<<1))

Comment: Probably not the fastest, because there is `(((x+3)>>1)&1) - ((x>>1)&1)`.

Comment: I love stuff like this

Comment: Sorry guys, my answer is faster than anything that uses a microprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n$ be defined like the coefficients of the series expansion at $x=0$ for 
$$
\frac1{1-x^2}=1-x^2+x^4-x^6\cdots=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n .
$$
You'll get your sequence by calculating:  $\displaystyle \;\;\;\left[\frac1{n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac1{1-x^2}\right]_{x=0}$.

Comment: Rodrigues-ish. You could also say $a_n=[x^{n}]$

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Sorry don't get it. Who's Rodrigues?

Comment: See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues'_formula)

Comment: @PeterTamaroff ahh, yeah I like([use](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/107169/19341)) this kind. But what do you mean with $[x^n]$?

Answer (score 0):

I like

```
function GetNumInSquence(int num)
{
    assert(num >= 0);

    int m_lookup[4] = { 1, 0, -1, 0 };
    int numInSquence = m_lookup[num % 4];
    return numInSequence;
}
```

No ifs or trig or anything; just a simple lookup. It's also easy to read the code. Someone else's `2*!(n % 4) - !(n % 2)` is really cool, but it requires explanation to know what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

In binary (twos compliment), $a_n$ is the following two-bit number:
$$(n_1 \cdot\bar{n}_0)  \ \ \ \  (\bar{n}_0)$$

where $n_1$ and $n_0$ are the two least significant bits of $n$, $\bar{x}$ denotes "NOT $x$" and $\cdot$ denotes the boolean "AND" operator.

That's how it would be done in some picoseconds using a handful of transistors. This would be written as a function in a [hardware description language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_description_language), which is then synthesized into digital hardware.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution using only 5 bitwise or arithmetic operations:

```
2 - (((x + 1) | (x + x)) & 3)
```

Comment: Your solution is too complicated. The simplest solution no one has yet posted is mathematical expression `n%2`. Please see my answer for an explanation how it works. http://math.stackexchange.com/a/134935/20207

Comment: @bodacydo - your solution is not a solution; it never outputs `-1`.