# Sequence of alternating $0$'s and $1$'s in terms of $i$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

How to redefine the function $f(n) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
0, & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}$ in terms of arithmetic operations using ⅈ?

Comment: Have you experimented with $(-1)^n$ and $i^n$?

Comment: yeah, but not enough. i just was curious about how $i$ can create different oscillations. [here, for example](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/130552/179228)

Comment: As you can see from the answer below, the powers of $i$ and $(-1)$ do give enough tools for building such a function. Don't judge too quickly. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $g(n)=i^{2n}$ maps even values to $+1$ and odd values to $-1$.

So you just need a function $h(n)$ such that:

- $h(+1)=1$
- $h(-1)=0$

This function is pretty simple: $h(n)=\dfrac{n+1}{2}$.

Now you just need to construct the function $f(n)=h(g(n))=\dfrac{i^{2n}+1}{2}$.

---

**UPDATE:**

Your piecewise function is from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, so clearly there is no need to "involve" $\mathbb{C}$ here.

As implied by @columbus8myhw in the comment-thread below, $i^{2n}=(i^2)^n=(-1)^n$.

Therefore, you might as well use $f(n)=\dfrac{(-1)^n+1}{2}$.

Comment: That can be written in a more simply as $\frac{(-1)^n+1}2$.

Comment: @columbus8myhw: I know, but OP asks to use $i$.

Comment: $\frac{(-1)^n+1}2+i-i$ works, then, if you want to be cheaty.

Comment: @columbus8myhw: Yeah, I've figured I could just add $0 \cdot i$, but I'm not sure if there is any point to that. In any case, OP's piecewise function is from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, so clearly there is no need to "involve" $\mathbb{C}$ here, unless that's really what you want to do (and I guess that's what OP wanted to do).

Comment: My guess is that he was interested in the "oscillatory" properties of $i^n$. However, _all_ roots of unity (not just $i$) have that property, including $-1$.

Comment: @columbus8myhw: OK, I added your suggestion to the answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: yeah, thanks guys. i was really interested in the "oscillatory properties". actually just i wanted to convert $\sum_{n\ge0}{z^{2n}}$ to $\sum_{n\ge0}{f(n)z^n}$. hmm... interesting how to generalize to the case of sum of $z^{kn}$

Comment: @DanyloDubinin You use other roots of unity. (I will agree, though - it _is_ an interesting problem.)

Answer (score 3):

$f(n) = \dfrac{1^n + (-1)^n}{2} = \dfrac{i^{4n} + i^{2n}}{2}$

Comment: hm... indeed. thanks.