# Find a closed form equation of the following sequence: ${0,0,-2,0,4,0,-6,...}$

Tags: closed-form, recursion

Find a closed form equation of the following sequence: ${{0,0,-2,0,4,0,-6,...}}$

I know $1+-1^n$ = 0 if n is odd and 1 if n is even.

However finding alternating signs when plugging in only even numbers seems to be difficult. I.e. finding a g(n) such that g(2)=-2, g(4)=4, g(6)=-6, and so forth.

Comment: Take any of the answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130547/getting-the-sequence-1-0-1-0-1-0-1-0-ldots-without-trig) and multiply by $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Henning Makholm's comment links to solutions not involving trigonometry.  Here is a simple real expression which does:

$$n \cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right).$$