# How do you create an alternating series with the sign being the same twice in a row?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I am working on a Taylor series question and I have created a series which alternates however, it does so in doubles. in other words it follows the following pattern: $x$, $x$, $-x$, $-x$, $x$, $x$,...

My goal is to write this series using summation notation. 
I know that to produce a normal alternative series I simply use $(-1)^n$. However, I've found this significantly harder to create in summation notation because any manipulation to the $(-1)^n$ part of the sum only moves the position where the alternating series starts. Any suggestions are appreciated!

edit: please note that in my example, "$x$" is just an arbitrary function and each other $x$ does not equal the other $x$'s.

Comment: How about $(-1)^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor}$?

Comment: Try using a variation of $\sin$ or $\cos$.

Comment: @NobleMushtak my taylor series is in fact just the one for the function sin(x) centered at PI/4. I'm not certain how to write this in summation notation.

Comment: @almagest yes thank you, this works!

Comment: As an alternative, depending on the form of your summands it may be worthwhile to groups the sum into pairs, i.e. for $f(0)+f(1)-f(2)-f(3)+\ldots$, you could use $\sum_i(-1)^i(f(2i)+f(2i+1))$.

Comment: @KlausDraeger You should make that an answer; it conveys the idea much better than finagling together a (hardly unique) function to give the right sign sequence, and it's what I'd expect to see in, e.g., a research paper.

Comment: Instead of using a somewhat contrived formula for such a simple concept, why not directly define the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=1, 1, -1, -1$, etc. and then directly refer to $a_n$ in your formula?

Comment: Regarding notation, if $a_n\geq 0$ you can write $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(a_{2 n}x^{2 n}+a_{2 n+1}x^{2 n+1}).$  Also, I have seen (rarely) $(a_0+a_1-a_2-a_3++--...)$. For an example, take the power series for $(1+x)/(1+x^2).$

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/823883.

Comment: analyzed here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130547/getting-the-sequence-1-0-1-0-1-0-1-0-ldots-without-trig

Answer (score 19):

If you are looking for a formula for the sequence $1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,\ldots$ then try some of the suggestions at [OEIS A057077](https://oeis.org/A057077), such as $$(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}$$

Comment: Suppose I take some simple series and use these signs with them, do I get something well-known? I was thinking $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}}{n}$$ i.e. the harmonic series taken with signs like this, is the sum of this series known?

Comment: Well, if we group every second term we get stuff like $\sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^{m-1} \left( \frac{1}{2m-1} \pm \frac{1}{2m} \right)$ which can be handled by Wolfram Alpha, so the answer is yes.

Comment: This answer is right.  It's (-1) raised to the power of the sum from 1 to n.  Note that for any given n, the sum from 1 to n has sign k (either + or -).  The next odd number added to the sum changes the sign, the next even number keeps the sign the same: so you get two odds, then two evens, then two odds, then two evens....

Comment: @JimZipCode nice way of looking at it :)

Answer (score 7):

It seems that you want to simulate the series $1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, ...$. These kinds of alternating series are usually easiest to do using $\sin$ or $\cos$ functions. (Although the formula $(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}$ works just as well, I think it's kind of interesting to see this series modeled with a trig function, so I'm going to do it anyway.)

Think about a $\cos$ function going through $(0, 1)$, $(1, 1)$, $(2, -1)$, $(3, -1)$, $(4, 1)$ and so on.

Where are the maximums and minimums? They're in between points with the same values, like $\frac{0+1} 2=0.5$ and $\frac{2+3} 2=2.5$.

Which is the maximum? It's the one in between the points of higher value, which is $0.5$. This represents our right shift since $\cos 0$ is the maximum.

What's the period? It's two times the difference between two consecutive extrema, or $2(2.5-0.5)=4$. The period is usually $2\pi$, so our coefficient of $x$ must be $\frac{2\pi} 4=\frac \pi 2$.

Thus, we have $\cos\left(\frac \pi 2\left(x-\frac 1 2\right)\right)$. However, this gives us $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ for $x=0$, so we must multiply by $\sqrt 2$ to get the following function:

$$f(x)=\sqrt 2\cos\left(\frac \pi 2\left(x-\frac 1 2\right)\right)$$

If we [put this into WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(2)*cos%28pi%2F2%28%7B0,+1,+2,+3,+4,+5,+6,+7%7D-1%2F2%29%29), we clearly see that this gives us the sequence we wanted.

Answer (score 6):

There is a very general way to attack the problem of writing a repeating sequence of coefficients.

The discrete Fourier transform of the sequence "$1,1,-1,-1$", of length $N=4$,  is $0,1+\mathrm{i},0,1-\mathrm{i}$".  This says that $$
    0 \mathrm{e}^{-2\pi \mathrm{i} \cdot 0 n /N} + (1+\mathrm{i}) \mathrm{e}^{-2\pi \mathrm{i} \cdot 1 n /N} + 0 \mathrm{e}^{-2\pi \mathrm{i} \cdot 2 n /N} + (1 - \mathrm{i}) \mathrm{e}^{-2\pi \mathrm{i} \cdot 3 n /N}
$$ is a constant multiple of your desired sequence.  ("Constant multiple" because there are constant premultipliers I have ignored to make the above more direct.)  That expression, in which we may ignore the two terms starting with zero, produces a sequence starting from $n=0$:  $$
    2, 2, -2, -2, 2, 2, -2, -2, \dots  \text{.}
$$  So, $$
\frac{(1+\mathrm{i}) \mathrm{e}^{-2\pi \mathrm{i} \cdot 1 n /4} + (1 - \mathrm{i}) \mathrm{e}^{-2\pi \mathrm{i} \cdot 3 n /4}}{2}
$$ does what you want.

Just as for $(-1)^n$, we may rewrite this using trigonometric functions.  $$
\left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)-\sin \left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)\right) (\cos (\pi  n)-i \sin (\pi  n))
$$

Say, instead of starting at $n=0$, you want to start at $n=1$.  We cyclically rotate the sequence to get the term we want at the position where $n=1$, i.e., we consider the sequence $-1,1,1,-1$.  This gives transform $0,-1+\mathrm{i}, 0, -1-\mathrm{i}$.  The term to use in your sum is then $$
\frac{(-1+\mathrm{i}) \mathrm{e}^{-2\pi \mathrm{i} \cdot 1 n /4} + (-1 - \mathrm{i}) \mathrm{e}^{-2\pi \mathrm{i} \cdot 3 n /4}}{2}  \text{,}
$$ which is equivalent to $$
\left(\sin \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)\right) (-\cos (\pi  n)+i \sin (\pi  n))  \text{.}
$$

Answer (score 4):

Just for kicks:

$$f(n)=\lim_{x\to n_-}\left\lfloor{\sin \frac{\pi x}{2}}\right\rfloor$$

This can be used to generalize sequences like:

$$\underbrace{1,1,1,\cdots,1}_{k \space1's},\underbrace{-1,-1,-1,\cdots,-1}_{k \space 1's}, 1\cdots $$

Can be represented as

$$f(n)=\lim_{x\to n_-} \left\lfloor{\sin \frac{\pi x}{k}}\right\rfloor$$

I thought that this might a bit cool for the OP.

Comment: Very creative (+1)

Answer (score 4):

$\frac{i^n+i^{-n}}2=\{1,0,-1,0,\dots\}$ has period $4$, so putting it together with itself shifted by one gives
$$
\{1,1,-1,-1,\dots\}=\overbrace{\frac{i^n+i^{-n}}2}^{1,0,-1,0,\dots}+\overbrace{\frac{i^{n-1}+i^{1-n}}2}^{0,1,0,-1,\dots}\tag{1}
$$

---

Using the series $-\log(1-x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac11-\frac12-\frac13+\frac14+\cdots
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{i^n+i^{-n}}2+\frac{i^{n-1}+i^{1-n}}2\right)\frac1n\\
&=-\frac12\log(1-i)-\frac12\log(1+i)+\frac i2\log(1-i)-\frac i2\log(1+i)\\
&=-\frac12\log(2)+\frac i2\log(-i)\\[6pt]
&=\frac{\pi-\log(4)}4\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it is difficult to see what everything after "Thus, using the series…" has to do with the question.

Comment: The question is answered in $(1)$. After that, I was applying this representation to the question posed in a comment by Jeppe Stig Nielsen about the usability of the representation $(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}$ in a series like $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}}{n}$$ In other words, $(2)$ is attempting to demonstrate usefulness.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to represent the sign sequence directly, you can also approach this problem by grouping you summands into pairs. So for a sum of the form

$f(0)+f(1)-f(2)-f(3)+f(4)+\dots$,

you would write

$\sum_i(-1)^i(f(2i)+f(2i+1))$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more "blunt force" way of doing this. Given a sequence like

$$1 + \frac12 - \frac13 -\frac14 + \frac15 + \frac16 - \frac17 - \frac18 + \cdots,$$

then you could notate it as follows:

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{s(n)}{n},$$
>   where
>   $$s(n) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } n \mod 4 = 1 \operatorname{or} 2, \\ -1 & \text{if } n \mod 4 = 3 \operatorname{or} 0\end{cases}$$