# How to find the formula for computing the coefficient?

Tags: power-series, binomial-coefficients, products

Suppose I have this expression:
$$\prod_{n=1}^{N} (1- x^n)$$
In the expansion of the product series how to find the general formula for finding the coefficient of $x^n$ ?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30009/what-is-prod-k-1n-1-xk

Comment: @Robert Z Thanks for editing but that link doesn't help

Comment: For suppose i have $$\prod_{n=1}^{4} (1- x^n)$$. On expanding i am getting 2 as the coefficient of $${x^5}$$. But your link doesn't give any rule to find out that value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.07504.pdf) recent paper related to your problem.

Comment: I already checked it. What went wrong? See my comment on Robert Z's post.

Comment: Thay which u r giving is for infinite products, although i have a finite one

Comment: I have changed the link. Kindly check it. It seems that finding the coefficient of $x^n$ is a challenging one.

Comment: i understand friend