# Calculate $\sum_{ k = 1 } ^ n \ln ( 1 - x ^ k )$

Tags: summation, logarithms, q-analogs, pochhammer-symbol

I am trying to calculate the following sum
$$f_n ( x ) = \sum_{ k = 1 } ^ n \ln ( 1 - x ^ k ), \qquad x \geq 0.$$
I first tried to use the power expansion of $\ln(1-u) = - \sum_{ m = 1 } ^ { \infty } \frac{ x^m } { m }$ but got stuck with infinite sums involving general terms of the form
$$\frac{1}{m}\frac{x^m}{1 - x^m} \quad \mbox{and} \quad \frac{1}{m}\frac{x^{m(n+1)}}{1 - x^m}.$$
I also tried to compute the value of $f_n'(x)$, buth this time I got stuck with a finite sum involving a general term of the form
$$\frac{k}{1 - x^k}.$$
If you have any idea, I would be happy to hear about it!

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps using $\ln A_1+ \ln A_2=\ln(A_1A_2)$ can be of some help.

Comment: Since $\ln(a) + \ln(b)\equiv\ln(a\cdot b)$, $\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^n\ln\left(1 - x^k\right)\equiv\ln\left(\prod_{k = 1}^n\left(1 - x^k\right)\right)$. Then, perhaps [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30009/what-is-prod-k-1n-1-xk) is useful? [This](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.07504.pdf) paper might be helpful.

Comment: that's related to [q-Pochammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol)