# How to find the sum or product of terms of the form $\frac{1}{1+e^k}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If the sequence is $\frac{1}{1+e}, \frac{1}{1+e^2}, \frac{1}{1+e^3}, \cdots, \frac{1}{1+e^n}$, how can I find the sum or product of the above sequence? That is $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{1+e^k}$$ and $$\prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{1+e^k}$$ The sequence is not an arithmetic, geometric, or harmonic progression, so what can I do?

Comment: Try entire series developpement? For the second one you should apply $\ln$ to it

Comment: Sorry for interfering. Pls show the full solution. It's a very interesting question

Comment: I don't think there is any easy formula, if you only need an estimate take the integral. Wolfram alpha says i is a digamma function.

Comment: pls send me the full solution.

Comment: I couldn't find a duplicate question, but I found some potentially relevant questions: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60311/infinite-series-of-the-form-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1ak1) (answers first question, if it were an infinite series) and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3702943/calculate-sum-k-1-n-ln-1-x-k) (is related to the second question, and has no answer, but does link to another related post, and a relevant paper).

Answer (score 2):

In terms of the [q-digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-gamma_function), there is an explicit solution for the sum
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{e^k+1}=\psi _{\frac{1}{e}}^{(0)}(1-i \pi )-\psi
   _{\frac{1}{e}}^{(0)}(n-i \pi +1)$$

This is nice but not very pactical if one does not access this special function.

The continuous case is much more simple
$$T_n=\int_{1}^{n} \frac{dk}{e^k+1}=n-1-\log \left(\frac{e+1}{e^n+1}\right)$$

The limit

$$L=\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{limit  }}\frac{S_n}{T_n}=\frac{\log \left(\frac{e-1}{e}\right)+\psi
   _{\frac{1}{e}}^{(0)}(1-i \pi )}{\log
   \left(\frac{e+1}{e}\right)}=1.48171172619\cdots$$ is very quickly atteinned from above (for example, if $n=10$, the ratio is $1.48184$).

So, an approximation
$$S_n \sim L\, T_n$$

For $n=2^p$, some numerical results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 p & \text{approximation} & \text{exact result} \\
 3 & 0.4636665402055017829693530 & 0.4639683019375577689499164   \\
 4 & 0.4641633490165810934671019 & 0.4641634502684112933990670   \\
 5 & 0.4641635157612409366699013 & 0.4641635157612523310631363   \\
 6 & 0.4641635157612597013124978 & 0.4641635157612597013124978   \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

An empirical correction could be
$$S_n \sim L\, T_n+e^{-(n+\frac 1 {10})}$$ which would give
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 p & \text{approximation} & \text{exact result} \\
 3 & 0.4639700793435806496302185 & 0.4639683019375577689499164   \\
 4 & 0.4641634508426180246671108 & 0.4641634502684112933990670   \\
 5 & 0.4641635157612523956807584 & 0.4641635157612523310631363   \\
 6 & 0.4641635157612597013124978 & 0.4641635157612597013124978   \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Similarly, using the [q-Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol), the product

$$P_n=\prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{e^k+1}=\frac{2}{(-1;e)_{n+1}}$$ could be compared to
$$Q_n=\exp\left(\text{Li}_2\left(-e^n\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{1}{e}\right)
   +\frac{3+\pi ^2}{6}   \right)$$

They are very highly correlated but all further analysis would be totally emperical.