# Generalizing this infinite series for Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Tags: number-theory, euler-mascheroni-constant

Define $\gamma(t)$ as
$$\gamma(t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=2^n}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k+t}. $$
We have $\gamma(0)=\gamma = 0.577....$ I want to find a closed form when $t>0$ is an integer. I believe $\gamma(1)= 1-\gamma$.

I found this paper by Sondow and Zudilin which is possible to find this series but I'm having difficult following it.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0304021.pdf

Another representation for the double sum is:
$$ \gamma(t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^1 \frac{x^{2^n}x^{t-1}}{1+x}dx$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define $\;d(t):=\gamma(t+1)+\gamma(t)\;$ then :
\begin{align}
d(t)& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=2^n}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k+t+1}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=2^n}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k+t}\\
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=2^n+1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k+t}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=2^n}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k+t}\\
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{2^n}}{2^n+t}\\
\tag{1}& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{2^n+t}\\
\end{align}

You may conclude that indeed $\gamma(1)=1-\gamma\;$ (since $\;d(0)=1$)
and obtain the next terms using $(1)$ or the [$\frac 12$-digamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html) :
$$\tag{2} d(t)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{2^n+t}= \frac{\psi_{1/2}(-\log_2(-t/2))}{t \log(2)}-\frac 1t$$

Comment: Mathematica is giving a complex number. Probably because log(-t). Why this sum is not real valued?

Comment: You may consider $(1)$ too as a Lambert-series (see for example [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60311/infinite-series-of-the-form-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1ak1) ). Anyway $(2)$ was provided by [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%281%2F%282%5En%2Bk%29%2Cn%3D1..infinity%29) which seems in pain with q-digamma...)

Comment: (the problem as indicated in the accepted answer is that these expressions are rather for $\dfrac 1{2^n-t}$ than for  $\dfrac 1{2^n+t}$  so that imaginary numbers will be used to change the sign. The same way $2$ will become $1/2$ because of the usual $2^n$ at the numerator of Lambert series. Shortly simple expressions for $(1)$ are hard to find in the litterature). See too [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4789334/how-to-find-the-sum-or-product-of-terms-of-the-form-frac11ek).